# Limit $\sqrt{3-x}$ as $x\to3^+$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying:
$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\sqrt{3-x}$$
Using real numbers, technically this limit does not exist. However,

```
Limit[f[x], x -> 3, Direction -> -1]
```

I also tried:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> 3, Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

And I tried:

```
Simplify[Limit[f[x], x -> 3, Direction -> -1], x \[Element] Reals]
```

Still, both gave an answer of zero.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `Limit[Sqrt[-3 - x], x -> 3, Direction -> -1, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` ... perhaps that may clarify things a little bit

Comment: The problem is that the assumption `x \[Element] Reals` constrains the `x` values, not `Sqrt[3-x]`; that is, `f[x]` is allowed to be imaginary and thus the limit returns `0`. If only there was a way to constrain `f[x]`, not `x`...

Comment: @JHM Thought I might have something with your comment. Tried `Limit[Re[Sqrt[3 - x]], x -> 3, Direction -> -1]`, but still got zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it results from a misunderstanding of the math and possibly also of the function `Limit`.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about the error message in the following probably leads you to the right conclusion:

```
Limit[Sqrt[3 - x], x -> 3, Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> Sqrt[3 - x] ∈ Reals]
```

> Limit::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Sqrt[-x] ∈  Reals && 0 < x < 1/4096 encountered. >>

---

Or I suppose you could go back to the definition:

```
Resolve[ForAll[e, 
  e > 0 \[Implies] 
   Exists[d, d > 0 &&
     ForAll[x, 3 < x < 3 + d \[Implies] 0 < Sqrt[3 - x] < e]]]]
(*
  False
*)
```

---

Maybe use the real n-th roots, [`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html).  This returns unevaluated:

```
Limit[Surd[3 - x, 2], x -> 3, Direction -> -1]
(*  Limit[Surd[3 - x, 2], x -> 3, Direction -> -1]  *)
```

But this works:

```
Limit[Surd[3 - x, 2], x -> 3, Direction -> 1]
(*  0  *)
```

Again, thinking about it might lead to a conclusion about why the first comes back unevaluated.

(Note: In all cases, what I mean to imply by "thinking about it" is that it is not immediately clear what to make of the output.  I realize from the OP's question that he is looking for *Mathematica* to give a clear answer.  So far none is forthcoming.)

Comment: Some amazing stuff here. Wow!