# How to properly input limit of real function of real variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

Consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\ln x)^x.$$

When restricted to real functions (no complex version of $\ln x$ or power), then this limit does not exist because the function is not defined in the neighborhood of $x=0$. Now if I put this into Mathematica, it yields $1$ as an answer:

```
Limit[Log[x]^x, x -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

I understand that Mathematica is using complex numbers by default, but is there a way to force it to use real functions/limits? Is there some way to handle real function limits in Mathematica without a priori knowing the function in question and performing tricks that will probably work only in specific case?

Comment: To match your mathematical notation, you should use `Direction -> -1` instead of `Direction -> 1`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh thanks, that was a mistake, fixed.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102981/limit-sqrt3-x-as-x-to3

Comment: I don't follow this at all. Have a look at `Plot[Abs[Log[x]^x], {x, .001, .1}]` and similar for `Arg`. The function not only exists in a one-sided neighborhood corresponding to the direction of approach, but it very clearly is showing a limit of 1.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But that is a complex Log and its Abs/Arg. In reals this would result in $(\ln x)^x = e^{x \ln\ln x}$, the inner $\ln x$ is negative when $x$ is close to $0$ so it results in $\ln$ of negative argument, which is not defined in real numbers. Or without the $e^x$,  we just have negative number to some arbitrary real number which again is not defined. Making plots without the Abs shows this (as actually nothing is being plotted...).

Comment: (1) The fact that the log is complex values has nothing to do with existence of a limit. And that limit can be (and is) real valued. All this is in the math, nothing to do with Mathematica. (2) Not that it matters here, but log ((log x)^x) need not equal x log log(x). Tha tpower law requires certain assumptions to be met. (Again, nothing to do with Mathematica.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes the limit might be a real number, but the specific example I have given is a real function of real variable and we are trying to find its limit (or decide it does not exist). I agree that in complex analysis there is no issue here.

Comment: Okay. Offhand I do not know if a way to restrict to reals within the context of seeking a limit. My thought is that one might try a two-pronged approach (so to speak), wherein `Limit` is used to get a candidate value (if one exists) and something separate is done afterward to determine if that value is valid for the real-only case. Offhand I do not know what to suggest for that second step though.

Comment: I should be clear about what prompted my earlier remarks. The post contains the statement "This limit does not exist since the function is not defined in the neighborhood of `x=0`." This is of course not correct, and what I imagine was intended would be more along the lines of "in the setting where we restrict to a real range, this cannot exist because..." That is to say, the remark gives the impression of claiming a bug rather than coming across as a question of how to "muzzle" `Limit` to a real-range restriction.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I see now, updated the wording to avoid confusion.

Comment: Makes much better sense now. Retracted my close vote. But I still don't have a good way to go about handling the problem in question.

Comment: Maybe the following can be generalized. (1) Use `ComplexExpand` on `Arg` or `Im` of function. (2) `Simplify` with a range restricting assumption. (3) See if result is not identically zero (or `Pi`, for the `Arg` case). Example: `In[599]:= Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[Log[x]^x]], 
 Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1/1000]

Out[599]= \[Pi] x` allows us to conclude the function is NOT real valued in the nbhd of interest, so we know to discard whatever `Limit` tells us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Limit[Log[x]^x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> (Log[x]^x) ∈ Reals]

During evaluation of Limit::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Log[x]^x∈Reals&&0<x<1/4096 encountered.

(* Limit[Log[x]^x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> Log[x]^x ∈ Reals] *)
```

#### More examples

From below:

```
Limit[Sqrt[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> Sqrt[x] ∈ Reals]

During evaluation of Limit::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Sqrt[-x]∈Reals&&0<x<1/4096 encountered.
(* Limit[Sqrt[x], x -> 0, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> Sqrt[x] ∈ Reals] *)
```

From above:

```
Limit[Sqrt[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> Sqrt[x] ∈ Reals]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Wow that was quick response. It seems to work, also in few other cases as you also provided. Going to play with this, but so far seems like it is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Sil I don't know how robust it is and what to make of that 1/4096.  There may be some numerical tests there.

Comment: I noticed that on wolfram alpha it gives different results, and it seems to ignore the whole Assumptions thing: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5Ex,+x+-%3E+0,+Direction+-%3E+-1,+++Assumptions%5BElement%5B(Log%5Bx%5D%5Ex),+Reals%5D%5D%5D . But it probably just accepts different syntax or has limited functionality, important is it work on desktop app.

Comment: @Sil Wolfram Alpha tries to interpret natural language input.  Even when it accepts something that looks like a Mathematica command, it often does something else than what Mathematica would do.  I find Wolfram Alpha rather unpredictable and don't use it much ...

Comment: The `1/4096` is the "delta" that `Limit` uses (as in delta-epsilon). ***If*** it works to reduce the problem to something decidable, you get a result. If not, maybe `Limit` tries something else or fails. I assume it was chosen heuristically by the developers to work in most use-cases. It's an exact value in order to be used for symbolic processing. One should be able to add a smaller delta with `Assumptions`. I recall running into a situation where `1/0496` wasn't small enough, but I cannot recall the details.